# partially connected application using asp.net 3.5 (not mobile apps)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

We had a requirement to build a ASP.NET 3.5 web application using web forms, WCF, ADO.NET and SQL Server. The users would connect via Internet.

Recently we understood that it is possible that users would often remain disconnected and would have Internet access intermittently.

I need to understand if we can create occasionally connected web application using asp.net 3.5 - what all technologies/features we need to use? Is MS Sync Framework the answer to the problem - is it a viable option to use with web application?

Is windows application the right approach instead of web applications - where the business logic would be run at the client itself, using local SQL Express editions with data then been synced up with Enterprise SQL server at server end when connection is established using replication and/or MS Sync framework. In that case is there a need to use WCF?

Does Silverlight applications help in this context -building paritally connected web apps?

Really appreciate if you can give pointers to how to go about this task of creating .net partially connected apps (not mobile apps)?

Comment: so you want us to design your architecture for you?

Comment: i would appreciate if you can tell me what combination of technologies would be the best way to go

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you'll need to store your client data locally when not connected.
If you use wcf you can determine what type of protocol to use according to connectivity without affecting your main code e.g. tcp/ip for LAN, http for internet and msmq for storing up data when disconnected.
If data for transfer is stored up using msmq, as soon as a connection is remade then the data will be passed to your main server.
If you write your wcf, or communications code to run as a service (assuming windows functionality here) then it is up to you whether to retain the asp code or write a new windows app.

*edit*

Setup MSMQ at both ends, its part of windows setup and can be installed on a client machine, just the same as IIS is, it's on the installation disk but not installed by default.

I wouldn't use it to get web pages, have those available on the local machine, but instead use it to queue up data that MUST get back to the server. Your data access layer should be separated from your GUI layer anyway. I assume that your using the MVC pattern or similar.

I don't know what your application is requried to do but here is the example that I've worked on.

A mobile user who visits clients. He has a replicated copy of a company product database on his laptop. When he visits client sites he may not be able to connect to his company server, but still wants to place client orders. This he does using his laptop based application and database. Order data is queued up in MSMQ on the laptop.

As soon as he is able to connect to his company server MSMQ automatically sends the order data. The server has queued up MSMQ messages of changes to pricing and stock etc. that took place whilst he was disconnected. These are now received and the local database is updated.

The choice of TCP/IP, HTTP or MSMQ all happens seemlessly to the main application, the WCF code copes with the choice.

Comment: Pls ignore my ignorance :) MSMQ is in web server right? If we cannot be connected to server how can I use MSMQ. If I am not wrong MSMQ can be used if say my web app wants to connect to another app who might not be able to process my request immediately. So we have request from my web app goign to MSMQ and then to second app. Here I am not sure when i would be connected to web app, so how can I use MSMQ? If application is to be deployed at every user's machine (windows app) why should i use WCF?

Comment: Am i right in understanding that it should be windows app (not web app) with MSMQ. Also WCF could be used at server end to pull data from MSMQ to database server whenever connected

Comment: You could use local ASP pages. For the application above I used WinForms because that is where my experience lies. If using WCF you'll need to have it running on both the client and the server end (for those direct comms instances using TCP/IP and HTTP). You'll also need to have MSMQ installed on the server.
If you run your communications layer as a service then it doesn't matter what your front end is, only that you can use it.

The same applies to your data layer. It shouldn't care what the front end is and if structured correctly you should be able to use it from a web app or a windows app.

Comment: I'm not sure requiring the user to install MSMQ on his machine is a very wise deployment scenario. And by "local ASP pages", do you imply that the user should also install IIS and deploy a website on his machine?

Comment: @Allon - no that is not what I said, but if you see my previous comment you'll note that ASP is not my forte. Perhaps you could suggest a solution for the OP instead? Either way if the end user is disconnected from the server for any length of time then there will have to be content locally for the user to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you have two options:

1. Use [Gears](http://gears.google.com/) (abandoned) or [Web Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage) to store and sync local data, combined with heavily javascripted web pages that can detect loss of connection and work against the local data store.
2. Use the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx) with a rich client ([WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb.aspx), [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) or possibly [Silverlight OOB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(VS.95).aspx) if it gets supported). The Sync Framework does not require a local installation of a database, instead it uses [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), which is simply a local file.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage using Sync franework with probably rich client seems to be better option. Thanks a lot Guys for taking your time out and trying to answer my queries. I will let you know the technologies used after i manage to deploy the app!